# How to restrict syncing to only calender and not contact

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, calendar, macos

I have contacts and calendar on my Mac but like to sync only the calendar to my android through google. Whenever I sync with google, both my local contacts and calendar are being synced. Because I have separate and different contacts on google, I like to only sync the calendar but not the contact. Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Accounts > Google Account > name@gmail.com

You can decide which features to keep synced up here.

Comment: Within that setting, there is only "Gmail" and "Contact"...